# How write Reads function for Scala Play

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I have problem with Reads. I have function like this:

```scala
  private val myFunc: Reads[Foo] =
    (__ \ "foo")
      .readNullable[Foo]
      .map {
        case Some(foo) => foo
        case None =>
          (__ \ "bar").readNullable[Bar].map {
            case Some(bar) => Foo(bar.value)
            case None => Foo("")
          }
      }
```

But I getting compiler problem like this:

```scala
[error]  found   : play.api.libs.json.Reads[com.me.Foo]
[error]  required:com.me.Foo
```

How I fix this?

Comment: BTW `Foo("")` makes me think there is a design issue an the `Foo` field must be an `Option[String]` rather than a `String` (`Option.empty[String]` vs `""` vs `null: String`)

Comment: @cchantep no Foo is case Foo(value : String)

Comment: Can you share your `Foo` and `Bar` definition, please?

Comment: I don't think `value` should be `String` if you end providing a `""` representing a missing (empty) value ... for me that's an optional value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Foo(lorem: String)

implicit val fooReads: Reads[Foo] = Json.reads[Foo]

case class Bar(value: String)

implicit val barReads: Reads[Bar] = Json.reads[Bar]

val reads: Reads[Foo] = (__ \ "foo").read[Foo].orElse {
  (__ \ "bar").readNullable[Bar].map {
    case Some(bar) => Foo(bar.value)
    case None => Foo("")
  }
}

// ---

Json.parse("""{"foo":{"lorem":"ipsum"}}""").validate(reads)
// JsSuccess(Foo(ipsum),/foo)

Json.parse("""{"bar":{"value":"ipsum"}}""").validate(reads)
// JsSuccess(Foo(ipsum),/bar)
```

As there is no value in instantiating `Bar` in the `orElse`:

```scala
val reads: Reads[Foo] = (__ \ "foo").read[Foo].orElse {
  (__ \ "bar" \ "value").readNullable[String].map {
    case Some(bar) => Foo(bar)
    case None => Foo("")
  }
}
```